# Pushing Hive query to database level

Tags: sql, database, apache-spark, hive

I have tabular data of 100 Million records, each record having 15 columns.
I need to query 3 columns of this data and filter out the records to be used in further processing.

Currently I'm deciding between two approaches

**Approach 1**
Store the data as a csv or parquet in HDFS. When I need to query read the whole data and query using Spark SQL.

**Approach 2**
Create a Hive table using HiveContext and persist the table and Hive-metadata. Query this table when needed using HiveContext.

Doubts:

1. In Approach 2, is the query pushed to database level(HDFS) and only the records which satisfy the criteria are read and returned? Or the entire data is read into memory(as is the case with most spark jobs) and then query is run using the metadata?
2. Runtime: Of the two approaches, which one will be faster?

Please note that the Hive setup isn't Hive over Spark, it's HiveContext provided with Spark.

Spark Version: 2.2.0

Comment: _"as a csv"_?! Why not parquet?!

Comment: Parquet is fine. It's just csv is the first instinct. I'll make the edit.

Answer (score 1):

**In approach2**, You should have hive table structured and stored in proper way.
Spark doesn't load all the data if hive table is partitioned and stored in file format that supports indexing(like ORC).
**Spark optimized engine will use partition pruning and predicate push down and load only relevant data for further processing(transformation/action).**

**Partition Pruning:**
choose appropriate column(which distribute data across partition evenly) to partition the hive table.
Spark partition pruning works efficiently with hive meta store. It will look into only relevant partition as per partition_column used in  WHERE clause  of your query.

**Predicate PushDown:**
ORC file has min/max index and bloom filters . Will work for string columns also in ORC(not sure about latest parquet string support), but more efficient on numerical column.
Spark will read only rows that are matching the filters as it pushed the filter down to underlying storage (orc files).
Below is a sample spark snippet to create such hive table. (assuming raw_df is the dataframe created from your raw data)

`sorted_df = raw_df .sort("column2")`
`sorted_df.write.mode("append").format("orc").partitionBy("column1").saveAsTable("hive_table_name")`

This will partition the data as per column1 values  save orc files in hdfs and update hive metastore.
Sorting the table using column2 assuming that we are going to use column2 in our query WHERE clause.(sort is needed for efficient orc index)

Then you can query hive and load spark dataframe with relevant data . below is the sample.
`filtered_df = spark.sql('SELECT column1,column2,column3 FROM hive_table_name WHERE column1= "some_value1" AND column2= "some_value2"')`

In above sample spark will look into only some_value1 partition as column1 is the partition column in hive table created .
Then Spark will push the predicate(i,e filter) "some_value2" for column2 in orc files only under "some_value1" partition.
Here Spark will load only values of column1,column2,column3 , ignoring even other columns in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you combine the second approach with more advanced storage layout (`bucketBy` / `DISTRIBUTE BY`) which can be used to optimize the query there shoulde be no difference between between these two as long as you don't use schema inference in the approach 1 (you'll have to provide schema for the `DataFrameReader`).

Bucketing can be used to optimize execution plans for joins, aggregations and filters on bucketing column, but everything is still executed with Spark. In general Spark will use Hive only as metastore, not as execution engine.

Comment: So using the more advanced storage layout, is it possible to push the query to database level? All the data wouldn't need to be read in memory?

Comment: Bucketing can be used to optimize joins, aggregations and filters on the bucketing column, but it doesn't push anything to "the database". It just uses layout and metadata to optimize Spark execution plan.